# Laravel PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (trying to connect via (null)) on PHP 8.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-8.0, php-8.2

I have been running a Laravel 9.52 application and everything worked fine until I updated my PHP 8.1 version to PHP 8.2.6.

The application uses an SSL certificate to connect to a remote MySQL 8 database. Here is my database connection array from `config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => (extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') && env('APP_ENV') != 'local') ? [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY'),
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT'),
    ] : [],
],
```

In my .env I have set the following variables

```
MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA
MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY
MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT
DB_CONNECTION
DB_HOST
DB_PORT
DB_DATABASE
DB_USERNAME
DB_PASSWORD
```

Now after upgrading to PHP 8.2.6, any attempt to connect to the database give me

> PDOException  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]  (trying to connect via (null))

I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

I hardcoded the environment variables from above in the `config/database.php` file and with PHP version 8.2 the application still throws `PDOException` when trying to connect to the remote DB.

I have also tried connecting to a local database and everything worked as expected.

I switched the PHP version back to 8.1 and the application successfully connected to the remote DB.

I consistently run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: `env('DATABASE_URL')` what is this value set as? It appears to be null currently.

Comment: can you try first to run it WITHOUT certificate ?

Comment: @Martin Yes, it is null.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I get the PDOException `SQLSTATE[HY000] [3159] Connections using insecure transport are prohibited while --require_secure_transport=ON.` when trying to connect without the certificate.

Comment: are you setting this var MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA  ? double check please

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Yes I am. I'm setting it in the .env

Comment: and you are on APP_ENV = ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator I've tried for both `APP_ENV=local` and `APP_ENV=staging`

Comment: comment/remove this condition to avoid headaches for a few minutes && env('APP_ENV') != 'local'

Comment: Still the same issue ? does not make sense to use a CA locally.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Yes, I still getting the same issue. The funny thing is if I run `sudo update-alternatives --config php` and switch the PHP version to 8.1, it works fine. When I switch back to PHP 8.2, I get the "trying to connect via null" error